# Do temp files get automatically deleted after Azure function stops

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function app with multiple Azure functions in it. The function app is running on the consumption plan and a linux os. In one of the Azure functions, each time it runs I'm saving a file to a /tmp directory so that I can use that file in the Azure function. After the Azure function stops running, if you don't delete this file from the /tmp directory will it automatically be deleted? And if it isn't automatically deleted, what's the security implications of having those files still there. I say this because, as I understand it, using the consumption plan means sharing resources with other people. I don't know if the tmp directory is part of those shared resources or not. But I'd rather not have other people be able to access files I write to the tmp directory. Thanks :)

I had read [here](https://option40.com/blog/azure)

> "Keep in mind though, that Functions is conceived as a serverless
> platform, and you should not depend on local disk access to do any
> kind of persistence. Whatever you store in that location will be
> deleted on other Function invocations."

I ran one of the Azure functions which uploads a file to that tmp directory each time it runs. From that link, I thought the files in tmp would be deleted each time I ran the function, but they persisted across each time that I ran the function. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Temp directory files are deleted automatically once in 12 hours of time but not after each run of the **function app** of if the function app is restarted.

It means the data stored in **temp** directory (For E.g., `D:\local\Temp)` in Azure, can exists up to the **function host** process is **alive** which means that temp data/files are **ephemeral**.

Persisted files are not shared among site instances and also cannot rely on those files by staying there. Hence, there are no security concerns here.

Please refer to the [Azure App Service File System temporary files](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files) GitHub Document for more information.